# Why is the output being printed after static init blocks (inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance, static

### Problem description

The following piece of code which is taken from  [OCA/OCP Java SE 7 Programmer I & II Study Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071772006) produces the following output:

```
r1 r4 pre b1 b2 r3 r2 hawk
```

**My Solution which was wrong**: `pre r1 r4 b1 b2 r3 r2 hawk`.

This is the logic that I followed:

- First we start by printing `pre` which is before the instantiation of `hawk()`
- What is in the `static` blocks will be printed first: `r1 r4`
- From the base class `Bird` we print what is in the block then what is in the constructor : `b1, b2`
- We move on to the first subclass `Raptor` and we print `r3, r2`
- Finally we print `hawk` which is in class `Hawk`

---

```
  class Bird {
        {System.out.print("b1 "); }
        public Bird() 
        { 
            System.out.print("b2 ");
        }
    }
    class Raptor extends Bird {
        static { System.out.print("r1 "); }
        public Raptor() 
        { 
            System.out.print("r2 "); 
        }
        { System.out.print("r3 "); }
        static { System.out.print("r4 "); }
    }
    class Hawk extends Raptor {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.print("pre ");
            new Hawk();
            System.out.println("hawk ");
        }
    }
```

---

### Explanation of the solution which is provided by the book

> Static init blocks are executed at class loading time; instance init
>   blocks run right after the call to super() in a constructor. When
>   multiple init blocks of a single type  occur in a class, they run in
>   order, from the top down.

---

## Questions

- **Static init blocks are executed at class loading time:** It's also the class loading time of Hawk right? When class hawk is loaded it will automatically go up the inheritance tree? Even before printing `pre`.
- Why isn't the solution : `r1 r4 b1 b2 r3 r2 pre hawk`
- It's like it went all the way up the inheritance to print what is in the `static` methods then came all the way down to print `pre`. Then it went all the way up again to print what the in the `blocks` and `constructors`. Then finally printed hawk.

It's a little confusing for me. Sorry If I butchered the java language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b1 b2 r3 r2` are not static, so while they are indeed part of the construction of the instance, they will be called only after it's created (`new Hawk();` which comes after `pre`)

Generally speaking, you are right about it going all the way up the ineritence tree, it does so twice:
- first time for the static part
- second time for the constructor stuff, triggered by creating new `Hack`, hence after the pre

Comment: Yes but why would `r3` be written before `r2`r

Comment: @JordanGS instance initialization blocks are executed before ctors

Comment: @HaniGoc - yes, they are both parts of static init blocks. pre is part of the static `main` method

Comment: really interesting. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The order of class loading is:

```
static initialization blocks
instance initialization blocks
constructor
```

When the `main` method of `Hawk` is called, its class hierarchy must be loaded. starting from the base class, the static initialization blocks will be called in order:

```
r1 r4
```

The first `println` is called

```
pre
```

the class is initialized from the bottom up. In each class the instance initialization blocks are called before the ctor. in `Bird`

```
b1 b2
```

in `Raptor`

```
r3 r2
```

then the last println is called

```
hawk
```